# configure: error: python3.7 interpreter not found

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, cross-compiling, yocto, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to upgrade the python recipe by using `devtool` from version 3.5.x to 3.7.6. At 95% I get the following error:

```
ERROR: python3-3.7.6-r0 do_configure: configure failed
ERROR: python3-3.7.6-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/temp/log.do_configure.15565)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/temp/log.do_configure.15565
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function externalsrc_configure_prefunc
| DEBUG: Python function externalsrc_configure_prefunc finished
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-32', 'arm-common', 'arm-32', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'arm-linux', 'arm-linux-gnueabi', 'common']
| DEBUG: Executing shell function autotools_preconfigure
| DEBUG: Shell function autotools_preconfigure finished
| DEBUG: Executing python function autotools_aclocals
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-32', 'arm-common', 'arm-32', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'arm-linux', 'arm-linux-gnueabi', 'common']
| DEBUG: Python function autotools_aclocals finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| automake (GNU automake) 1.15.1
| Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
| License GPLv2+: GNU GPL version 2 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html>
| This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
| There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
|
| Written by Tom Tromey <tromey@redhat.com>
|        and Alexandre Duret-Lutz <adl@gnu.org>.
| AUTOV is 1.15
| NOTE: Executing ACLOCAL="aclocal --system-acdir=/home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/aclocal/ --automake-acdir=/home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal-1.15" autoreconf --verbose --install --force --exclude=autopoint -I /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/workspace/sources/python3/m4/ -I /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/
| autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
| autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
| autoreconf: running: aclocal --system-acdir=/home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/aclocal/ --automake-acdir=/home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal-1.15 -I /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/workspace/sources/python3/m4/ -I /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/ --force
| autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
| autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
| autoreconf: running: /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/autoconf --include=/home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/workspace/sources/python3/m4/ --include=/home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/ --force
| autoreconf: running: /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/autoheader --include=/home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/workspace/sources/python3/m4/ --include=/home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/ --force
| autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Automake
| autoreconf: running: gnu-configize
| autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
| NOTE: Running ../../../../../../workspace/sources/python3/configure  --build=x86_64-linux               --host=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi                   --target=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi                 --prefix=/usr                   --exec_prefix=/usr              --bindir=/usr/bin               --sbindir=/usr/sbin    --libexecdir=/usr/libexec                --datadir=/usr/share            --sysconfdir=/etc               --sharedstatedir=/com                   --localstatedir=/var            --libdir=/usr/lib               --includedir=/usr/include               --oldincludedir=/usr/include            --infodir=/usr/share/info      --mandir=/usr/share/man                  --disable-silent-rules                  --disable-dependency-tracking                   --with-libtool-sysroot=/home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot  --with-system-ffi    --with-threads   --with-pymalloc   --without-cxx-main   --with-signal-module   --enable-shared   --enable-ipv6=yes   ac_cv_header_bluetooth_bluetooth_h=no ac_cv_header_bluetooth_h=no     CROSSPYTHONPATH=/home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/ --without-ensurepip
| configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-silent-rules, --disable-dependency-tracking, --with-libtool-sysroot, --with-threads, --with-signal-module
| configure: loading site script /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/sources/poky/meta/site/endian-little
| configure: loading site script /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/sources/poky/meta/site/arm-common
| configure: loading site script /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/sources/poky/meta/site/arm-32
| configure: loading site script /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/sources/poky/meta/site/common-linux
| configure: loading site script /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/sources/poky/meta/site/common-glibc
| configure: loading site script /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/sources/poky/meta/site/arm-linux
| configure: loading site script /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/sources/poky/meta/site/common
| configure: loading site script /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/site/endian-little
| configure: loading site script /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi_config_site.d/ncurses_config
| configure: loading site script /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi_config_site.d/glibc_config
| checking for git... found
| checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
| checking host system type... arm-poky-linux-gnueabi
| checking for python3.7... no
| checking for python3... python3
| checking for python interpreter for cross build... configure: error: python3.7 interpreter not found
| NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.
| NOTE: /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/python3-3.7.6/config.log
| ERROR: configure failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3/3.7.6-r0/temp/log.do_configure.15565)
ERROR: Task (/home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/workspace/recipes/python3/python3_3.7.6.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 598 tasks of which 597 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/cladm1/fsimx6-Y2020.03/build/yocto-2.4-fus/build/workspace/recipes/python3/python3_3.7.6.bb:do_configure
Summary: There were 3 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Even though python is correctly configured on my system.

Using python3.8 will output same error as well.

Why is it failing? Is there any alternative?